# Backbone.syphon.deserialize not set the values of nested form fields?

Tags: backbone.js

We have a user details form having nested form fields like phoneNumbers[cell][value], phoneNumbers[home][value] etc. When we used syphon.deserialize to push the values, all other form fields like first name, last name etc set the value, but the values are not set in nested form fields. Do we need any other settings for nested form fields? Please suggest a solution.

Thanks in advance